# How to validate AWS Cognito session code returned from Cognito CustomUI login page

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I configured Cognito to use the custom website that AWS Cognito provides for signup/signin as specified here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-ui-customization.html

I am perfectly able to signup and login within the AWS Cognito page:

```
https://<your_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_app_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_callback_url>
```

The problem is that, after a successful login, Cognito redirect to the redirect page that I set, and the redirect includes a "code" value as a GET parameter.

I can not find documentation of how to use that "code" parameter, but it surely needs to be validated by my Python backend in order to check if that code is a valid session for a given user.

Can you provide a sample Python code (using or not a library, maybe Warrant) and JavaScript code that can validate that "code" parameter? and also to get the email/name of the user of that "code" parameter?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Authorization Code Grant flow, it requires the following to be done in order to get a short lived id_token, long lived refresh_token and an access_token.

Note: This is the most difficult flow to implement. If you need a simplified authentication flow, use the **implicit grant** flow, which will return the id_token once the user logins with the login page.

For Authorization Code flow, it requires the following

1. Receive Authorization Code from the Login Redirect URL. The code is not for recurrent use and only needs to be used to get the access tokens.
2. This code can be exchanged for access tokens using a token endpoint provided by AWS Cognito. You need to send a HTTP POST request in the following format (Without PKCE).

   GET https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?
   response_type=code&
   client_id=ad398u21ijw3s9w3939&
   redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/redirect_uri&
   state=STATE&
   scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin

   For more details read the [Token Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) documentation.
3. After receiving the tokens, store the refresh_token in a safe place to get new id_tokens and use the id_token to access the APIs.

Comment: In the step 2, I do not have the client ID, because after the user register themselves in the Cognito SignUp Page, I only receive the "code" and not the client_id parameter.

Comment: Also, I found out that if I use response_type=token in the Cognito Login URL, the redirect of the step 1. returns me the id_token and the access_token but not the refresh token. Do you know how can I get the refresh_token given these two previous values? And also, How should I use these three tokens to get for example the email of the user?

Comment: Just tried to have the authorization code grant flow along with response_type=token, and it returns the jwt token in return. That should be enough to get all the client credentials after decoding the token. We should then be able to use this data to set any session parameters needed.

Comment: According to oauth.net: "The OAuth 2.0 Security Best Current Practice document recommends _against_ using the Implicit flow entirely, and OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps describes the technique of using the *authorization code* flow with PKCE." 
So the flow used in the original question is actually the right one.

Answer (score 1):

The code that is returned is in the format of a jwt token.  It's not clear to me exactly what the format of this token is

I don't have any sample python code (yet, this is a current interest/project) but there is Javascript code here https://github.com/aws/chalice/issues/563

Comment: That code only call a random API, and with the result you can check if the user is authenticated or not. It does not seem to be the right solution. I believe cognito must provide a way to check the validity of this JWT Token.

Answer (score 0):

you can get token using code value. To achieve this u have hit token api endpoint which was provided from cognito. Refer following url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

Find below sample Request header's content-type should be same which was here used.
That Authorization hashsecret have to generate with using clientid and clientsecret.

```
req=requests.post('https://<paste domain here>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization':'Basic <secret hash here>'},data={                                
                            'grant_type'='authorization_code',
                            'client_id':'<client id here>',
                            'code':'<code here>',
                            'redirect_uri':'<redirect uri here>'}
```